# Using exiftool to overwrite the GPS of a photo, the location information is not displayed on my iphone

Tags: python, ios, video, gps, exiftool

I tried to modify the video GPS through exiftool, but when I checked the video details, the video GPSPosition was not displayed. Although the data was indeed written when using *exiftool -s filepath* to check GPS positioning

code as follow:

```py
import subprocess

metadata={
    'GPSLatitudeRef':'North',
    'GPSLongitudeRef':'East',
    'GPSAltitudeRef':'Above Sea Level',
    'GPSTimeStamp':'07:07:23',
    'GPSDateStamp':'2024:02:23',
    'GPSAltitude':'0 m Above Sea Level',
    'GPSDateTime':'2024:02:23 07:07:23Z',
    'GPSLatitude':'40 deg 2\' 17.65" N',
    'GPSLongitude':'116 deg 19\' 35.25" E',
    'GPSPosition':'40 deg 2\' 17.65" N, 116 deg 19\' 35.25" E'
}
for tag, value in metadata.items():
    command = ['exiftool', f'-{tag}={value}', "IMG_20240223_150725.MOV"]
    subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
```

Do I need to provide any other information？

I hope the video position can display as follows：

[video with gps position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbcQS.png)

Comment: Support of metadata in PNG files is poor with most software.  It's quite possible that the phone doesn't read EXIF data in PNGs.  Try your command with a jpeg.  If that works, then the phone simply doesn't read PNG metadata.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Not only pictures,but also the modification of the geographic of video files is ineffective.